# Is this DNF right?

Tags: disjunctive-normal-form

The question asks to convert $\neg(p \lor \neg q) \rightarrow (\neg r \land (p \rightarrow r))$ to a DNF.

I got it till $\neg(\neg p \land q) \lor (\neg r \land \neg p)$. I dont know how to simplify it further. I know that the first clause can be simplified further using DeMorgans but then it would become a disjunct instead of a conjunct. What should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert to Disjunctive Normal Form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3517910/how-to-convert-to-disjunctive-normal-form)

Answer (score 0):

With De Morgan's laws, you get
$$(p~\lor~\neg q)~\lor~(\neg r~\land~\neg p)$$
which might be confusing but it actually **is** in DNF. Why?
Note that disjunction (the OR) is associative. This means that  for any formulas $A, B$ and $C$,
$$(A~\lor~B)~\lor~ C~\equiv~A~\lor~(B~\lor~ C)~\equiv~A~\lor~B~\lor~ C$$

You can use associativity in your formula to remove the confusing parentheses, and then you obtain
$$p~\lor~(\neg q)~\lor~(\neg r~\land~\neg p)$$